# Return GraphQL JSON from Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, sangria

We are using Sangria Graphql to handle relay queries .
The Graphql code on getting a query from UI produces a kafka message and a appropriate microservice consumes and processes it and in turn posts a message to kafka which the Graphql code consumes .
The problem is that how would our graphql consumer map the result to the original request and send it back as to the client end ?

```
val StoreType = ObjectType("Store", List[Field[UserRepo, Unit]](

Field("cart", Cart,
  arguments = cart_id :: user_id :: sku_id :: quantity :: price :: operation :: Nil,
  resolve = c ⇒ c.ctx.callCartService(c arg cart_id, c arg user_id, c arg sku_id, c arg quantity,c arg price, c arg operation))
```

))

The callCartService will produce the message to kafka to be sent to the cart micro service which will send back a cart message to kafka for Graphql to consume .

```
QueryParser.parse(query) match {

          // query parsed successfully, time to execute it!
          case Success(queryAst) =>
            complete(Executor.execute(SchemaDefinition.schema, queryAst, new UserRepo,
              variables = vars,
              operationName = operation
            ))

          // can't parse GraphQL query, return error
          case Failure(error) =>
            complete(BadRequest, JsObject("error" -> JsString(error.getMessage)))
        }
      }
```

Is there a way for the complete to wait for the consumer to read the cart message and return to the client ?